# Setting tag for an imageview

Tags: java, android

I use an adapter to create views, with mIDS an array of numbers.
The setTag function doesn't seem to work, as the system.out line produces null for every view.
What am I doing wrong?

```
    ImageView view = imageViews[position];
    view.setImageBitmap(bmparray[position]);
    view.setTag(mIDs[position]);
    System.out.println("tag[pos] =  " + view.getTag(mIDs[position]));
```

Comment: Does your mIDs[position] has something?

Comment: @azael System.out.println("tag[" + position + "] =  " + mID[position]);
shows correct output, except that position 0 is given twice both at the beginning and the end of the sequence

Comment: What sequence? And where is the null you talked about?

Comment: @greenapps It does this for every view that is added, and the view at position 0 is 'created' twice at first, and then after all the other views are added to the grid it is created twice again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
view.getTag(mIDs[position])
```

Change to

```
view.getTag()
```